# Django/python querysets - adding another "child" queryset as an item to each list object?

Tags: python, django, typeerror, django-queryset

Apologies if the answer to this is obvious - I'm very new to django/python & haven't been able to find a solution in my searching so far.

I have a straightforward queryset, eg

```
members = LibraryMembers.objects.all()
```

with this I can do:-

```
for m in members:
  member_books = LibraryBorrows.objects.filter(member_id=m[u'id'])
```

What I really want though is to be able to serialize the results into json, so it looks something like this:-

```
{
  "members":
  [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "Joe Bloggs"
      "books":
      [
        {
          "name" : "Five Go Exploring",
          "author" : "Enid Blyton",
        },
        {
          "name" : "Princess of Mars",
          "author" : "Edgar Rice Burroughs",
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To my mind, the obvious thing to try was:-

```
for m in members:
  m[u'books'] = LibraryBorrows.objects.filter(member_id=m[u'id'])
```

However I'm getting TypeError: 'LibraryBorrows' object does not support item assignment

Is there any way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: you should use .get to receive an item. The .filter gives you again a queryset. one_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed your model code, in particular, the relations between the two models.

Comment: There are no relations built in (can't because of how the data's populated from an external source).  Its simply two separate classes with a bunch of fields, with a many-to-one relationship based on a one of the field's values as shown in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Well `m` is a `LibraryMember` object so you won't be able to treat it as a dictionary. As a side note: Most people don't name the models in plural form since they are just a class *modeling an object*, not a collection of objects.

One possible solution is to make a list of dictionaries with the values that you need from both objects, something like this in a one-liner:

```
o = [ { "id": m.id, "name": m.name, "books": [{"name": b.name, "author": b.author} for b in m.libraryborrows_set.all()] } for m in LibraryMembers.objects.all()]
```

Note that you can use the [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/relations/) to get the books for a given member. For better clarity:

```
o = []
for m in LibraryMembers.objects.all():
   member_books = [{"name": b.name, "author": b.author} for b in m.libraryborrows_set.all()] 
   o.append( { "id": m.id, "name": m.name, "books": member_books } )
```

**EDIT**:

To serialize all the fields:

```
members = []
for member in LibraryMembers.objects.all():
    member_details = {}
    for field in member._meta.get_all_field_names():
        member_details[field] = getattr(member, field)
    books = []
    for book in member.librayborrows_set.all():
        book_details = {}
        for field in book._meta.get_all_field_names():
            book_details[field] = getattr(book, field)
        books.append(book_details)
    member_details['books'] = books
    members.append(member_details)
```

I also found DjangoFullSerializers which I hadn't heard about until today:

http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers

Comment: in my particular case (not the above example, which was illustration only), each table has over 20 fields.  Naming them all is ... painful :\  I'll experiment though with what you've suggested & see if it takes me somewhere, thanks.

Comment: Why build full Model instances then build a dict using `__getattribute__` (FWIW it should really be `getattr(instance, name)`) when you can use `Queryset.values()` which returns the very same dict without all the overhead of Model instanciation ?

Comment: thanks guys, that's looking very promising.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Corrected, thanks... I have the bad habit of calling magic methods, like `__getattribute__()`.

Answer (score 1):

Model instances are not indeed not dicts. Now if you want dicts instead of model instances, then `Queryset.values()` is your friend - you get a list of dicts with only the required fields, and you avoid the overhead of retrieving unneeded fields from the database and building full-blown model instances.

```
>> members = LibraryMember.objects.values("id", "name")
>> print members
[{"id" : 1, "name" : "Joe Bloggs"},]
```

Then you code would look like:

```
members = LibraryMember.objects.values("id", "name")
for m in members: 
    m["books"] = LibraryBorrows.objects.filter(
      member_id=m['id']
      ).values("name", "author")
```

Now you still have to issue one additionnal db query for each parent row which may not be that efficient, depending on the number of LibraryMember. If you have hundreds or more LibraryMember, a better approach would be to query on the LibraryBorrow instead, including the related fields from LibraryMember, then regroup the rows based on LibraryMember id, ie:

```
from itertools import group_by

def filter_row(row):
    for name in ("librarymember__id", "librarymember__name"):
        del row[name]
    return row

members = []
rows = LibraryBorrow.objects.values(
    'name', 'author', 'librarymember__id', 'librarymember__name'
     ).order_by('librarymember__id')


for key, group in group_by(rows, lambda r: r['librarymember__id']):
    group = list(group)     
    member = {
      'id' : group[0]['librarymember_id'], 
      'name':group[0]['librarymember_name']
      'books' = [filter_row(row) for row in group] 
       }
    members.append(member)
```

NB : this can be seen as premature optimization (and would be if you only have a couple LibraryMember in your db), but trading hundreds or more queries for one single query and a bit of postprocessing usually makes a real difference for "real life" datasets.